# Acrobat Reader Auto-Update Not Updating Consistently Across Domain

Tags: windows, windows-10, adobe-reader, microsoft

I discovered that 90% of an approx. 1000 computer network are not automatically updating Acrobat Reader (free).

AFAIK, Adobe Reader automatically downloads and installs updates in a truly seamless manner - In theory, a zero-touch approach for administrators. It does this by creating a Windows scheduled task upon installation, called "Adobe Acrobat Update Task". It runs the task under the user's context (INTERACTIVE), and executes "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe" at user logon, and at 11am each day.

For 10% of my machines, this works just fine. If I remote onto a machine with a previous version and an update has just released, I can manually run the task, and it works exactly as expected - Within minutes, the new version is evident upon running Reader.

For the other 90% (rough figures), this inexplicably does nothing. The task runs. AdobeARM.exe runs. That much I can prove. But the app just doesn't update. No matter how long I wait. In this scenario, they definitely have the old version, and I know there's a new version - All the task does is run AdobeARM.exe, which it does successfully, and yet.

I could accept this better if 10% of my machines didn't work. It's the inconsistency that gets me. People have told me "we must have something on our network" blocking it. Really? We have SOEs applied and a high level of software and hardware standardisation. Most of what's true for one machine is the same as the next.

I get around this by using PDQ Deploy to push out the new version - Which requires me to download the new version and release the deployment. Very little work, but some parties still complain it's not fully zero-touch, and the app has its own zero-touch auto-updater. They think we should be trying harder to find the reason why 90% just don't update - I can find no evidence of literature for such, nothing to point me in a valid direction.

Has anyone here ever encountered this phenomenon, and what did you do to solve it?

Afterthought: As I write this, it occurs that perhaps the problem is the scheduled task running under the user's context (INTERACTIVE) - About 90% of users don't have local admin rights. Perhaps AdobeARM.exe needs local admin to perform its update task. I'll entertain and seek to prove that theory.

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering, why the auto updater did not update me to the latest version, while a manual update check would. I think I've figured out what's going on. This [guide for the Acrobat-Reader Updater](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/837/cpsid_83709/attachments/Acrobat_Reader_Updater.pdf) was a helpful resource for this.

### The short answer

The auto updater immediately stops if not at least 3 days have passed since the last "full" updater run. Therefore the update should be installed after waiting for a few days.

### How to troublshoot and force an early update

The updater's log file is located at `%temp%\AdobeARM.log` (e.g. `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\AdobeARM.log`)

In my case it contained the following information about the last update run:

```
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0397] Adobe ARM 1.824.460.1052 logging started.
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0444] Too soon to check for arm update
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0451] ProductCode: {AC76BA86-1031-1033-7760-BC15014EA700}
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0451] ProductName: Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0451] ProductVersion: 23.003.20284
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0451] ProductUACPatching: enabled
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0499] Using registered preference AUTO_ALL
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0499] Last check for updates not expired, code: 120300
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0500] Using registered preference AUTO_ALL
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0500] Last check for updates not expired, code: 120300
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0709] ARM returns ERROR_SUCCESS
[2023-09-13 10:47:10:0709] Adobe ARM 1.824.460.1052 logging finished.
```

The update process stops after `Last check for updates not expired` is determined, despite version `23.003.20284` being out of date. The current version would be `23.006.20320` (which contains an important [0-day RCE bugfix](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/acrobat/apsb23-34.html)).

The [updater guide](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/837/cpsid_83709/attachments/Acrobat_Reader_Updater.pdf) states the following:

> By default, the Updater performs an update check every 3 days and records the year and day of the last successful check in two cases:
>
> - No updates are found in the manifest for system’s current product configuration.
> - Updates have been found and successfully installed.

This timestamp is recorded under the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe ARM\1.0\ARM` in `tLastT_Acrobat`. Deleting or renaming `tLastT_Acrobat` will force the updater to actually install the current version on it's next run.

Cheers! :)